# How to implement a node-VIEWNAME.tpl.php with Drupal Views module?

Tags: drupal, view, themes

I am working with Drupal and Views module.

I am using the same theme with different Views.

I have created different pages which are listing nodes per viewname as this : views-view-fields--VIEWNAME--page.tpl.php but now when I click on an article title, I would like to personalize the node with the viewname, so I would like to use node-VIEWNAME.tpl.php, but it's not possible. The only thing I can do, is to create a node-TYPE.tpl.php but I do not want to follow this way.

So my question is how can I implement (may be with a hook function?) the node-VIEWNAME.tpl.php when I click on an article title (so when I have only one full article and which is defined by it's id in the url. This is for precision, I am not fluent in English.

Thank you very much !

Alexandre

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do what you're attempting - use the Display Suite module, set the view to point to a Display Suite object in the field settings, then click the gear next to that setting and pick the build mode you want to use. Then in your template.php file, do whatever special work you need to do to that build mode.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I will try this ;-) But can i do it differently, without install a new module ? So as I said, with a hook implentation for example ?

Comment: You can use a built in build mode if you don't need them for anything else - sticky or teaser, for example. Otherwise you'd need to override actual view templates, likew views-view--viewname--row.tpl.php, etc. You can see the specific available templates, their contents, and candidate file names, by clicking "Them Information" in the bottom of the left column in the Views UI

Comment: Thank David, but I use Drupal 6 and Views 2, so i haven't this options.
I know how to personnalize the list page, which list multiple articles, but once you will click on an article, you arrived on a page which contains a single article, and it is this page I would like to redefine in function of the viewname. I am blocked for I use the same theme with differents views, so I can't edit the node.tpl.php whish is used, and I would like to use node-VIEWNAME.tpl.php.

Comment: You can do what I described in Drupal 6. In fact you can NOT do what I described in Drupal 7, as Views 3 is totally different.